# Python Eric IDE: Execute selection in console

Tags: python, ide, eric-ide

This is such a simple question, but I cannot figure out the answer.

I have installed the Eric 6 IDE for Python. It has an interactive console - great! How can I execute selected commands in the console?

PyCharm has <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, Spyder has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> ... what is the corresponding command in Eric?

Answer (score 1):

If you select your code and right click on it, it has an option for "Execute Selection In Console"

There is a "Keyboard Shortcuts" under the "Settings" menu, where several items can be personalized. However, I don't see a way to assign a shortcut for "Execute Selection In Console". If anyone else finds a way to do it, I would love to know.